# Unable to find activity declared in other package

Tags: java, android, package

When clicking a button in my application, I want to start an activity from another package.

This is my intent:

```
  final Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.facebook.android.Places.class)
```

and this is my manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".com.facebook.android.Places"
            > </activity>
```

But i am getting `unable to find explicit  activity com.mypackage\com.facebook.android.Places`.

Is it impissible to start activity from another package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't start an Activity from another library-project:

Create your own subclass of it:

```
public class MyPlaces extends com.facebook.android.Places {

@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      ...
   }
}
```

Now declare your new Activity in your Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MyPlaces"> </activity>
```

Comment: I will only create a subclass and copy the same code from places in it, as I dont want is to do anything different?

Comment: Do you want to use a library project or start an activity of another app?

Answer (score 2):

```
<activity android:name=".com.facebook.android.Places"> </activity>
```

Is the Places activity inside the package com.facebook.android? or is it in com.mypackage.com.facebook.android?

If the Places class is in com.facebook.android, change the manifest entry to

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.android.Places"> </activity>
```

You dont have to start the name with "."